# Docker Compose does not create containers in defined subnet

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file which defines a network subnet:

```
networks:
  <net-name>:
  name: my-network
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
    config:
      - subnet: 172.21.1.0/16
```

When i run `docker-compose up` the created containers **(all on the same network)** are not in this defined subnet, but on the default `172.21.0.X/16`, as seen in the `docker network inspect <net-name>`:

```
      "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.21.1.0/16"
            }
        ]
    },

      ...

      "Containers": {
        "7fe928549faaa7da71a8b75b668ab6b5dae9e337e8abc7c379b3aa685cccf136": {
            "Name": "container1",
            "EndpointID": "724c4e86574b72e49afe0729e053d2b7c7285ec07e350f1efb8a3dff9b9f2d22",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "ead40f068d7a4b657c09fb583bdcc229cd2cda2e46876c0bdc602388f19a15bb": {
            "Name": "container2",
            "EndpointID": "7759ba9bea74496278f74780c49d94e035d1e9c8c330837ea81e95b4d7485da0",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "f4c18290c832705d83840108c38769b27f418a2845e92aebcd2afc920c519a95": {
            "Name": "container3",
            "EndpointID": "7ca9be45cea2f5833ea5f673acccce08721e0bf6fff581dad70da7143bb19e03",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.4/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
```

The reason this is a problem for me, is that internally in the containers I listen for specific IP adresses, and not everywhere can I use docker DNS resolution. I also have two compose services, which are separated by these subnets, one on `172.21.0.0/16` and the other on `172.21.1.0/16`

How can I enforce compose containers to be created on the compose network subnet?

Comment: What's your docker-compose version?

Comment: version: "3.8" latest

Comment: Can you set the applications to listen on all interfaces (0.0.0.0) instead of trying to manually configure the Docker networking?

Comment: That would be a partial solution yes.
But I would like to limit the allowed "trusted" addresses as the application is in contact with a database of basically most of our source, it is secured by AD but still a surface I'd like to minimize.

Comment: Actually, the problem was my understanding in networking. The proper subnet mask for my setup should be /24 and not /16.